# Construct a continuous function $F:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ that has a point with period 2015

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, chaos-theory

> Construct a continuous function $F:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ that has a point with period 2015.

I think I should do it with Sharkovskii's theorem, but then? Where can I start with?

Or try to find a point of period 3 and by LiYorke theorem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something as simple as 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}x-\frac{1}{2014}& \text{for }x>\frac{1}{2014}\\
1-2014x & \text{for } x\leq \frac{1}{2014}
\end{cases}$$

Then $f^{2015}(1)=1$, and $f^n(1)\neq 1$ for $n<2015.$

---

**Addendum**

Of course this works for every natural period.  Here's what the cobweb plot looks like when when the period is $15$.

[image]

Comment: hmm, but f^2015(1)=0, actually.

Comment: Ah, yes Fixed that.

Comment: Nice!  I hope you don't mind that I added a cobweb plot - feel free to roll back, if so.